# Integrating YouTube channel into android app

Tags: android

How can I integrate youtube channel into my android app? I have already got working code on how to integrate a given youtube video, but not a youtube channel. Can anyone please provide step-by-step instructions and a working code snippet on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored)
    {
        if(!wasRestored)
        {
            player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
        }
    }

Comment: The cueVideo() is used to integrate video into the app.